# Yii Relative Path Include File

Tags: php, yii

Here's my URL on localhost:

```
http://localhost/ss/index.php?r=myc/mya
```

myc has a method `actionmya` which simply calls the corresponding view file

```
public function actionmya()
{
    $this->render('mya');
}
```

My view folder has a php file `mya.php` where i want to include another script `myfile.php` kept in a folder named `myfolder`within the view folder

I tried to include it this way in `mya.php`:

```
include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/myfolder/myfile.php');
```

However it generates an error:

```
include(C:\xampp\htdocs\ss\protected\views\myc/myfolder/myfile.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

I tried swapping backslashe and forward slashes on my windows pc but none work despite the fact that the file in clearly there in the location specified above.

How do i include the file in my view file ?

Comment: is myscript.ph is == myfile.php ?

Comment: @oops that was a mistake.. corrected the question yes now i want to include myfile.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well ... you first said that the file that you want to include is named `myscript.ph` (it probably has a full `.php` extension at the end in reality?) but then, you are including it with the name `myfile.php` . Please specify the correct file name in your include statement and it would certainly work.

Comment: @QuakiGabbar then it should work with backslashes. I am on ubuntu and I was able to produce this exact same error by using backslashes. But it is working with forward slashes. As you are on windows so you should use backslashes.

Comment: myfault there again.. there was a spelling mistake in my filename in my actual code.. guess its time to take a nap :(

Answer (score 1):

The issue **might** be in the way you are calling include.
The include method does not require parentheses (); just give it the string.
Or in the directory separator, (even though, I personally have not had any problem with windows accepting linux separators)

try this

```
 include dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'myfolder'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. 'myfile.php';
```